# Replace Directory Path Without Changing All Paths

Tags: notepad++

I'm not quite sure how to word this, but I think the examples will make it understandable. I have a txt file with paths leading to files. Some paths are one directory deeper than the other files I need changed to new directories. They are all in the same root path, therefore a basic find and replace would add the new path to every entry, which I don't want:

Common paths:

```
\maindirectory\dir1\file1.txt
\maindirectory\dir2\file2.txt
```

Paths needing changes:

```
\maindirectory\file.exe
\maindirectory\file900.doc
```

To:

```
\maindirectory\newdir\file.exe
\maindirectory\newdir\file900.doc
```

Is there any way to find and replace what isn't in a directory past "\maindirectory", or the file, and then change the line to "\maindirectory\newdir" without adding "\maindirectory\newdir\dir1", or having to change line by line?

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Regular Expressions](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/#regular-expressions) for this.

1. Open the "Find and Replace" dialog and select "Regular Expression" as the search mode.
2. Enter the following pattern in the "Find what" field:

   ```
   (\\maindirectory\\)([^\\]+)$
   ```
3. Enter the following in the "Replace with field:

   ```
   \1newdir\\\2
   ```
4. Click "Replace All".

**See it in action:**

[image: Demo]

**[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/76Fbno/1).**

**Pattern explanation:**

- `(\\maindirectory\\)` Match "\maindirectory" literally and capture it in group 1.
- `([^\\]+)` Match one or more characters other than "" and capture them in group 2.

And then the replacement is basically:

> Whatever was captured in group 1 + `"newdir\"` + whatever was captured in group 2.

Answer (score -1):

After some tinkering and testing, I was able to come up with the following solution:

First, Find and Replace with **Normal** expression:

```
Find: \maindirectory\
Replace: \maindirectory\newdir\
```

Then use a **Regular** expression find and replace:

```
Find: \\maindirectory\\(\b.+?)\\(\b.+?)\\
Replace: \\maindirectory\\$2\\
```

What this did was add \maindirectory\newdir\ to every line, and then used a regular expression line to remove the second directory (\$2\) if 3 existed, therefore merging the old paths back to how they were. I hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: Note that `\b` shouldn't be used here. It might cause some false-negatives in this case (i.e., if your dir starts with a non-alphanumeric character like "@something", for example). Also, there's no need to do two find-and-replace operations. This can be achieved using just one as demonstrated in my answer.

Comment: Actually, not in my case, because `(\\maindirectory\\)([^\\]+)$` grabs more than one line at a time. I think it depends on per list format.

Comment: You could replace the `[^\\]+` part with `[^\\\r\n]+` or with `.+?` (as you did in your answer; just without `\b`).